# Convert simple isometric image to 3D

Tags: algorithm, 3d, language-agnostic, computational-geometry, voxel

I'm curious how one would deduce 3D coordinates in simple isometric images.
[image: A simple isometric image with five colors: (0) background, (1) contour lines, (2) edges facing in X direction, (3) edges facing in Z direction, and (4) edges facing in Y direction]
The only approach I could come up with is to do depth-first searches to find the vertices of each face and then use complex branching logic to figure out the vertex position from all the possibilities there are for how faces can be partially hidden. What would be a better approach to go about this?

This is just for hobby, so I'm fine with simplifying the problem further (say by requiring the scene to be composed of only unit voxels or by giving the solution only as coordinates of the midpoints of individual voxels instead of giving the coordinates and their face indices in counter-clockwise order).

I'd assume the input to be given as a matrix of the five different colors I use in the picture. As output I'd expect a list of 3D coordinates, possibly accompanied by a list of coordinate indices for the faces.

Comment: Are you trying to deduce coordinates from only analyzing the image?  If so, do each of the 5 colors represent a different type of shading?  Like top, right side, left side, border, NUL/BG ?

Comment: One other note - from the image, the tile behind the 3 height tower in the center could be any height value from 1 to negative forever if "holes" are allowed in the floor.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yes, I want to deduce coordinates from only analyzing the image and you're correct about what the colors represent. For tiles that are undecidable I'd let the algorithm pick any of the possible solution and then fix things up manually where necessary.

Comment: Then the hard part really is just the height.  Because the tiles are all the exact same size, if they were also the same height, you could just do a simple little coordinate transformation to find the X/Y values.  Basically, transform the space from isometric back to top-down view and then `div` by square edge size (or rectangles if you want to leave it "tipped" and only do a 2D rotation).  I'd start with just that.

Comment: You can take a look at *Waltz algorithm*: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/46927-f97/slides/Lec5/sld021.htm

Comment: For Height, I'd start at the bottom of the image (call that tile 0,0) and scan up until you find a "top color".   From there, scan "down" and count the number of "edge to left/right transitions" you see until you hit NUL/BG.  That is that tiles height.  This fails if the tile is a "hole" but again, it is a start.  Scan the next tile, say the one up and left of the lowest (say tile 1,0) and repeat.  You can "floodfill" all top tiles within the same "top" color area the same height.

Comment: For holes, you will need to scan upwards looking for transitions and "subtract" the number of left/right/edge color transitions you find.  Pretty sure that combined, this will work.  And yes, sounds very similar to the algorithm posted above.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan That seems like a good start, because I'm not very experienced in writing constraint solving algorithms yet, which I think I'd need for Yves' solution, but not for the simple cases of your approach and then I can still add it on later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are able to detect all edges and their direction (among six possilbe). Also if they are complete or occluded. And detect the vertices, so that you get a 2D graph.

Assign the coordinates (0, 0, 0) to some point, such as the lowest vertex. Then following every complete edge from the already known points, you will obtain the coordinates of the endpoints by considering the edge direction (and possibly length) and you will know which coordinate to increment/decrement.

In the end, you will get all coordinates of the endpoints of the complete edges, tell the complete faces, and be able to tell the occluded faces.

[image]

Comment: Sounds so simple that I really don't understand how it would work :)  Might need a bit of example to help me.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll play around a bit with it this weekend and see if this can solve my problem.